# SQL query to get the youtube id out of a embed code

Tags: mysql, sql, database, youtube

I have bunch of video data like this:

```
 <object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie" 
 value="http://www.youtube.com/v/2rwPGGdB1_4?version=3&hl=uk_UA&rel=0">
 </param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param 
 name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed 
 src="http://www.youtube.com/v/2rwPGGdB1_4?version=3&hl=uk_UA&rel=0" 
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" 
 allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

I want to select and export ids from this set of information, as new site excepts ids only. So I should somehow grab the part between v/ and ?. How can I do this in SQL query?

Comment: Sorry, I have formatted code

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that with pure MySQL. REGEXP only works as a filter and thus returns 0 or 1 as result, without providing access to the capturing group.

Solutions include either a custom function or using a different DBMS, as long as you want to do it strictly within SQL.
[How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

If it is possible for you to use any kind of scripting or compiled language, something like

```js
'<object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie"  value="http://www.youtube.com/v/2rwPGGdB1_4?version=3&hl=uk_UA&rel=0"> </param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param  name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed  src="http://www.youtube.com/v/2rwPGGdB1_4?version=3&hl=uk_UA&rel=0"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315"  allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>'.match(/youtube\.com\/v\/([^?]+)?/);
```

should do the trick and, if PCRE compatible, would return the video id in the second capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

I have found kind of solution in MySql. First, I have found the index of '/v/' with `SELECT exvid_code, LOCATE('/v/', exvid_code), LOCATE('?', exvid_code) FROM`exvid

After that, I have done substring to grab id:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(exvid_code, 83,10) AS id FROM `exvid`
```